# Developer Story won't let me add a new position unless my old position has an end date

Tags: bug, developer-story

I've just changed jobs and I tried to update my developer story.

However, I could not add my start date to June 2019 (neither May 2019). When I start typing, it automatically fills with 2018 and I can't edit it. In the end, I couldn't add a new position, I just can't add something without a date there...

A suggestion: default start date to "today" when we don't add a date. I'm not sure if it would help solving this issue, but I think it would be nice...

--

Edit: I just added my new position. To do that, I had to firstly update my old position, putting an end date to it. I believe it is still a bug - can't someone have two jobs at the same time? Or, if it is supposed to allow only one job per period, why it just don't add an end date automatically to the previous job?

Comment: Definitely should be considered a bug -- I had the same surprise when my HR department told me our provisioning app had to allow for new hires being hired for not just one position, but *3+* positions simultaneously...

Comment: LinkedIn allows it!

Comment: Short term you could put "Old Position & New Position" as the new position's title

Comment: Starting a new job as well and as I am a team lead I didn't want to burn my old company too much by leaving (it's a startup) so I agreed to a three month period where I work part time for my new company and old company. I wouldn't say it's a common thing, but it's definitely not a rare thing either.

Comment: Contractors/Consultants will also work for multiple companies at the same time (their Ltd company, agency (probably not to be included here), client, client's client)

Comment: I had 2 jobs once - I was a developer during the day and a teacher at night...